# How I can call 2 rows from one table to show up in jtable

Tags: java, mysql

I have this code and I want to show up 2 rows in jtable from one table.

```
public ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> getproList()
 {
     ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> proList =new ArrayList <Update_del_insert_products> ();
     Connection connection =getConnection();

     String query ="SELECT Pro_Id, Pro_Name FROM Products";
     Statement stt;
     ResultSet rss;
     try{
        stt = connection.createStatement();
        rss = stt.executeQuery(query);
        Update_del_insert_products  update_del_insert_products ;
        while(rss.next())
        {
           update_del_insert_products = new Update_del_insert_products (rss.getString("Pro_Id"),rss.getString("Pro_Name"),rss.getString("Pro_Price"),rss.getString("Pro_Quantity"),rss.getString("Pro_Supplier_id"),rss.getString("Pro_Tax"));
           proList.add(update_del_insert_products);
        }
        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
     return proList;
 } 
 public void show_Products_in_Jtable(){
     ArrayList<Update_del_insert_products> list= getproList();

     DefaultTableModel model =(DefaultTableModel)jTable_Prordes.getModel();
     Object[] row =new Object[2];
     for(int i =0;i< list.size();i++)
     {   
         row[0] = list.get(i).getpro_Id();
         row[1] = list.get(i).getpro_Name();


         model.addRow(row);

     }

 }
```

And I am getting this error

```
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The column name Pro_Price 
 is not valid.
```

I think he expect to add the other rows  from my table ?  is there i right code so i can gettext from only specific  rows or maybe sqlquery that can bring me this columns .Cause this columns have already prices so  i just want them to show up in my jtable  ty  !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't that pretty obvious since you are not fetching that column at all as per your below query.

```
SELECT Pro_Id, Pro_Name FROM Products
```

If you really need to fetch that column `rss.getString("Pro_Price")` then include that column in your query

```
SELECT Pro_Id, Pro_Name, Pro_Price,
Pro_Quantity, Pro_Supplier_id, Pro_Tax
FROM Products
```